# What rule does numpy.histogramdd use to calculate the number of bins?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I'm using [numpy.histogram2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) to generate a 2D histogram without passing a value for the (optional) `bins` argument, which means `numpy` obtains it automatically.
For what I can gather that function is based on [numpy.histogramdd](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html).

My question is: when I pass no `bins` argument, what rule is this function using to calculate the number of bins used in the histogram returned?

I took a look at [the code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L230) for the `histogramdd` function but couldn't really figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code for `histogramdd` it simply uses the parameter `bins=10` from the function definition when it's not given.

From your link:

```
def histogramdd(sample, bins=10, range=None, normed=False, weights=None):
```

Comment: Thanks @Wolph, I missed that. Say, wouldn't it be better to use some of the more simple "optimized" rules like `bins=np.sqrt(len(x))` instead of a fixed `10` value?

Comment: Generally I would expect someone to have their own preference and 10 is a fairly ok size for this. For me personally, I've used the histogram feature for about 20 items but also for a few million giving 4 to 1000+ bins. Not too usable ;) The binsize is automatically calculated which is the important thing.